# How are delegates useful?

Tags: jquery

I have two handlers for a mouseover function, I would like to know what the difference is and how to use each one in the most efficient way possible.

*Code block one:*

```
$('.test div').mouseover(function() {
                    $(this).stop().animate({
                        left: '100px'
                    }, 550);
});
```

*Code block two:*

```
$('.test').delegate('div', 'mouseover', function() {
                    $(this).stop().animate({
                        left: '100px'
                    }, 550);
                });
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Awwww, you think I'm a doll. Thank you :-P

Comment: @Klaus, he was clearly talking to *ME*.

Comment: @nickf, you lucky bastard :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) attaches *one* `mouseover` event handler per `.test` element, rather than each `.test div` match, and works for future `<div>` elements added inside those `.test` elements you called `.delegate()` on.

If you don't have more than a few `<div>` elements inside each `.test` and they're not changing dynamically (adding via AJAX for example) you can bind directly.  In other cases where they're dynamically changing or there are just many, use `.delegate()` since the startup cost is *much* cheaper, and the bubble/selector cost is minuscule.

Answer (score 2):

That's all in the doc: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

First of all, delegate are similar to "live" in the sense that it will apply to objects created in the future. So you should actually compare it to:

```
    $('.test div').live('mouseover', function() {
                        $(this).stop().animate({
                            left: '100px'
                        }, 550);
```

Now, the difference is that with delegate, it will apply for div created after the command is called, but not for .test created after. If you use live on $(

Using live() or delegate() has a cost in performances so if you don't need it you should stick with handlers that only apply to already created elements.

Answer (score 0):

> Delegates attach one or more events
>   for all elements that match the
>   selector, now or in the future, based
>   on a specific set of root elements.

Taken from [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 0):

From what I know about delegate is that it allows you to modify the Event.target. So let's say your Element is clicked, you can re-target to the DIV.